# Redundant __packed__ attributes

Tags: c, gcc, bit-fields, type-punning

This code is for Microchip's PIC32MX microprocessor. Their compiler is essentially GCC 3.4.

I tend use GCC's [`__packed__` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bpacked_007d-attribute-1670) to pack bitfields into a union, and later retrieve them as an `unsigned char` (ie. type-punning) for sending over SPI or I2C. This behaviour is all defined by my implementation, and works perfectly. I prefer this to a hundred or so lines of masking and shifting :)

My question is: are there `__packed__` attributes in the code below that are redundant? At first glance, I would think that those on the top-level union members can be dispensed with, but I'm not so sure. Or can I leave out those in the nested struct?

```
// Remember that bitfields cannot straddle word boundaries!
typedef struct
{
    /// Some flag #1
    unsigned FlagOne            : 1 __attribute__((packed));
    /// Some flag #2
    unsigned FlagTwo            : 1 __attribute__((packed));
    /// A chunk of data
    unsigned SomeData           : 5 __attribute__((packed));

    // and so on, maybe up to 32 bits long depending on the destination

} BlobForSomeChip;

/// This kind of type-punning is implementation defined. Read Appendix A (A7, A12) of
/// the MPLAB C Compiler for PIC32 MCUs manual.
typedef union
{
    /// Access the members of this union to set flags, etc
    BlobForSomeChip blobdata __attribute__((packed));

    /// As a byte for sending via SPI, I2C etc
    unsigned char bytes[4] __attribute__((packed));

} BlobData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I recommend compiling with `-Wall`.

Now:

1. The `BlobForSomeChip` struct has 7 bits declared. Normally, it would be 4 bytes long due to alignment, but with packed attributes it will be only 1 byte long.
2. A `unsigned char[4]` can't be packed. It will always be 4 bytes long, no matter what.

In short:

1. `struct BlobForSomeChip` = 1 byte
2. `unsigned char[4]` = 4 bytes
3. `BlobData` = 4 bytes (its largest member's size).

Concluding, the packed attributes on `BlobData` are not required. GCC will simply ignore them if used - see the output using `-Wall`.

Comment: For point 1 above - the `// and so on` comment was meant to imply that it could be anything up to 32 bits long. I would normally pad anything short of an 8 bit multiple with unnamed bitfields. So consider also the case that `BlobForSomeChip` is exactly 32 bits (but your explanation should apply then as well, I think).

Comment: @detly: correct, the size in bytes is always ceil(total bits / 8). The packed attribute only removes padding/alignment. N explicit/declared bits will always be N bits.

Comment: `-Wall` does not seem to catch this on GCC 3.4 (at least in MC's compiler). I'll check against the Debian packaged version. But other than that, good explanation, thanks :)

Comment: Oh, for the sake of completeness, if my bitfield struct **is** incomplete (ie. < 32 bits), is the way in which it is aligned relative to the other union member defined by the standard, by the implementation, or not at all?

Comment: @detly: sorry, I didn't pay attention to the compiler version you mentioned. That may be correct, I guess only GCC>=4.1 checks for this, my bad. As for the last comment, there's no alignment between members of an union because all members start at the same address - the union's address. And since there will be no padding, its size always matches its largest member size.